# JPA query for parent and child Model

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework, hql

Since 3 days I am looking for a solution to my problem. Traditionally I have a `table` and its `detail table` in mysql. It is done with `JPA play framework 1.2.x`. I need to implement a query having purpose of filter. I have an Event model object and every Event has features. The relation between them is as below.

```
@Entity(name="event")
public class Event extends Model{
public String name;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "event", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Features> features;
}

@Entity(name ="features")
public class Features extends Model{
public String name;
@ManyToOne
public Event event;
}
```

So, after that i need to query my data according to `feature id`. For example if `feature_id` come for 1,2 and 3. my `query` should return only the `events` which has features having 1,2 and 3 id.

I really need your help stackoverflow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select e from Event e 
where 3 = (select count(f.id) from Feature f where f.id in (1, 2, 3) and f.event = e)
```

should do the trick (it assumes that  given event doesn't have multiples instances of the same feature, though).

To generalize it, let's say `idSet` is your set of feature IDs, the query would thus be

```
select e from Event e 
where :idCount = (select count(f.id) from Feature f where f.id in :ids and f.event = e)
```

and you would bind `idSet.size()` to `idCount`, and `idSet` to `ids`.

The query could also be written as the following, which would also make it work for a ManyToMany association:

```
select e from Event e 
where :idCount = (select count(f.id) from Event e2 
                  join e2.features f 
                  where f.id in :ids 
                  and e2 = e)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it worked really. But I can not implement IN clause in JPA hibernate query. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: If two events can have the same feature, then your mapping is wrong: it should be a ManyToMany, and not a OneToMany. The query could easily be adapted to this though.